# Access to private member from static helper function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for a way to implement friend/private functions that requires access to a nested private class. I'd like to avoid declaring it in the header file, to abstract the implementation details and to avoid bloating the header. These functions should not be called outside the source file they're implemented in as well.

Ideally it would be a static function, but somehow with access to private class/member.

I've read that a nameless namespace would help me solving the latter issue at least, is this correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the PImpl idiom as defined in the [Guru of the week #100](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) and [#101](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/) by Herb Sutter.

The idea is to define a public interface containig an opaque handle to a private interface:

```
// PUBLIC INTERFACE
struct API
{
    void some_function();

private:
    struct Impl; // not necessarily a nested type
    Impl* pImpl;
};
```

with implementation as follows

```
#include <private_interface.h>
void API::some_function() { pImpl->some_function(); }
```

with the private interface being

```
// PRIVATE INTERFACE
struct API::Impl
{
    void some_function() { /* actual code */ }
};
```

Comment: NB (since OP specifically said a nested private class) - it's also fine to move the `Impl` forward declaration into the private section of `API`, and define it later as `API::Impl`.

Comment: Wouldn't I run into the same issue if Impl->some_function calls a static helper function, that requires access to API private class?

Comment: `API::Impl::some_function` must be self-sufficient. `API` is just a shell around it. The code goes to the private interface and its implementation.

Comment: Or probably just an abstract class. Pimpl is great when you need a class with value semantics.

Comment: The trick here is that the API::Impl definition header is ONLY included in the source-code implementation file of your API, and is not exported as an API file. So even though it is all public, clients to your API can't get to it. Yes an interface base class gives a similar level of abstraction, though you do need to publish a factory method, and that makes them impossible to interface with make_shared and similar value wrappers.